# C# WinForms DataGridView - Constant Row Selected!

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a winforms datagridview that seems to always have at least one row selected all the time. I'm not interested in being able to select the rows at all really, I just need the user to be able to select the checkbox in column 1.
Any ideas why there is always at least 1 row selected?
How can i prevent this?
Will it affect the ability to select the checkbox in column1?

Below are my Datagridview settings:

```
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
this.dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
this.dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 0;

colSelect = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
colSelect.HeaderText = "Select Message";
colSelect.Width = 90;
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, colSelect);
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "msgSelect";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [DataGridView.ClearSelection()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.clearselection.aspx) to remove any selection(s) after you have populated your DataGridView.

Also you can make specific columns read only allow which would allow to restrict editing to your checkbox column only. See [DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Goober, I encountered a similar problem, where I needed user to select rows using checkboxes. The first row is always selected by default after the gridview is populated irrespective of the gridview settings. To make sure the first row is not selected, everytime the gridview is populated, do a ClearSelection():

```
this.dgridvw.DataSource = this.MyTable;
this.dgridvw.ClearSelection();
```

ClearSelection() clears all the selected rows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are **NOT** calling the method to load the data from the form constructor. If you call it from the form.load()

also after the datagridview is loaded do this

DataGridView.Rows[0].Selected = false;

Answer (score -1):

Select the datagridview. Then, in the properties window scroll down until you find the property SelectionMode and change it to FullColumnSelect.

Alternatively if you want them to just select one checkbox at a time change it to CellSelect

Comment: Really? The reason why there is one row selected is because that is what your selection mode is set to! Hence to stop selecting "one row" you need to change it...

Comment: I don't think you understood the question Calanus. He wants to know how he can stop the DataGridView from selecting the first row in the list by default.